Providing a formula for the Hessian of a composition $L \circ z$.
Let $z: \mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $L: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $C^{3}$ functions.
For $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, one can use the chain rule to obtain the following formula for the gradient
$$\nabla_{\theta}(L \circ z) = J^{T} \nabla_{z}L$$
where $J \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ is the Jacobian matrix of $z$ with respect to i.e. $J_{ij} = \partial{z}_{i}/\partial{\theta}_{j}$.
My calculus is a bit rusty, how can one derive the Hessian matrix $\nabla^{2}_{\theta}(L \circ z)$ from here?
Any approach is much appreciated.
I usually think of gradients as being dual to the differential, i.e. $d(L \circ z)_{\theta}(\xi) = \langle \nabla_{\theta}(L \circ z), \xi \rangle$. But I got confused when considering the second differential
$$d^{2}(L \circ z)_{\theta}(\xi)(\nu)$$, where I'm trying to think of the Hessian as the matrix corresponding to the bilinear form that sends $(\xi, \nu) \mapsto d^{2}(L \circ z)_{\theta}(\xi)(\nu)$.
Context
I'm actually trying to understand equation (4) in the following paper:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2401.10809
